# Excel dynamic sheet reference in my lookup VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am new to VBA. I have a macro enabled template that I would like to have fetch data from a macro enabled workbook whose name is different every time (Filename will have letter with the Julian date followed by a series of (4) numbers if it matters).

An example of the two are attached. I am unable to share the actual files.

The macro workbook (in this example test.xlsx) has many sheets, the data entry sheet will always be the same, however the sample name/# worksheets will change based on the sample ID. I will pull data into the template (in this example book2.xlsm) and then save it as a file afterwards (and ideally will write this into the VBA code).

I have been able to get the following code below to work for at least the data entry sheet

```
Sub copydata()
Dim rw As Long, x As Range
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("/Users/andreaoverman/desktop/test.xlsx")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Data entry").Range("A1:GZ400")

With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For rw = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 11, False)
    Next rw

End With

With twb.Sheets("sheet1")

         For rw = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 3) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 12, False)
    Next rw

End With

    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Essentially, I want to have a cell (A1) that I will input a file name into that it will pull the information from (source folder will be similar for ease of use, likely desktop). I have tried using Indirect with Vlookup for this and got it to work fine, however, because I email this file out to report the data I want the values hard coded into it so it doesn’t ask to update to the reference file. Thus I wanted to use VBA.

[Book 2 shows the template I want to pull data into.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY8aY.png)

[Test shows what the file might look like that it is coming from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9KhV.png)

Can someone guide me towards how I can achieve this?

Comment: [This question is duplicate of](https://superuser.com/questions/1592308/vba-vlookup-across-sample-sheets-in-another-workbook)  please delete this and better improve your previous question !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Vlookup across sample sheets in another workbook](https://superuser.com/questions/1592308/vba-vlookup-across-sample-sheets-in-another-workbook)

Comment: It is duplicate code but I am asking how to do a different thing. Here I want to know how to dynamically reference a file name in cell A1 that the macro will open and pull the info from.