# VBA Vlookup across sample sheets in another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the below code to look up data in another workbook and collect the data. I have been able to [get it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFOwY.png) in book 2.xlsm [for my data entry sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HN1d.png) that is located in test.xlsx

```
Sub copydata()
Dim rw As Long, x As Range
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("/Users/username/desktop/test.xlsx")
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Data entry").Range("A1:GZ400")

With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For rw = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 11, False)
    Next rw

End With

With twb.Sheets("sheet1")

         For rw = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 3) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 12, False)
    Next rw

End With

    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

What I want to be able to do is also get VBA to pull (I'm guessing using a combo of indirect and vlookup?) [the integral data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJb2v.png) from the additional sheets in test.xlsx and place in book2 integral values. These sheet names in test.xlsx will change based on the sample name, but those names will be the same names that are in sheet1 of book2, same for the integral names.

Can someone help guide me to how I can add on to this code and address this?
I am new to VBA so I am still learning. My actual documents are much larger and so I will need to tweak the reference cells in the end so please try to explain what some of the things mean so I know what I will be doing.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: How can I modify the above code so that it will also look for the sample "integral values" in book 2 on the corresponding sample sheets in test.xlsx? I don't know how to make it dynamically reference the sheets as well. The cell location of the integral value will be the same every time.

Comment: if the cell location of the value you want is always the same, just use that. integral 1 is `twb.sheets(2).range("H10").value` (note: just written offhand, not tested). what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Alex M, the cell location is pretty well always the same, however, the sheet name will change with the sample name. I'm not sure how to dynamically reference the sheet name. Sample 1 name will be R202850920 for and then sample 1 will be R202860418 for the next today for instance. I'm hoping there is a way I can use the sample name in the cell, A4 for instance, to tell it which sheet to look at in the new workbook.

Comment: Yes, you can. Again, declare a string variable to hold the sheet name, and a worksheet variable to identify it by, and if the sheet name is going to be in A4, set the value of the string variable to the value of A4, then set the value of the sheet variable to use that string. Etc. This will be a lot easier if you [edit] your question to include a simple and complete description of your requirement.